# asp.net role provider redirect

Tags: asp.net, redirect, roleprovider

Could anyone provide me with an example of "how to redirect user to a specific page after login" uisng asp.net role provider.

On my login page, I have implement the ILogOnView , but it only redirects users to the home page not the page I specified in the web.config file. Here are the code that I used in the web.config file.

Code from Logon.aspx

```
<asp:Login ID="Login1" runat="server" DestinationPageUrl="Templates.aspx"  OnAuthenticate="Login1_Authenticate">
                                </asp:Login>

<forms 
     cookieless="UseCookies" 
     defaultUrl="Templates.aspx"
         loginUrl="LogOn.aspx" 
     protection="All" 
     timeout="2880">
        </forms>
```

```
public partial class LogOn : System.Web.UI.Page, ILogOnView
{
    private LogOnPresenter presenter;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        presenter = LogOnPresenter.Create(this);
    }


    protected void Login1_Authenticate(object sender, AuthenticateEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Membership.ValidateUser(Login1.UserName, Login1.Password) == true)
        {
            Login1.Visible = true;
            Session["user"] = User.Identity.Name;
            FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(Login1.UserName, true);
        }
        else
        {
            Response.Write("Invalid Login");
        }
    }


    public void Redirect(string targetUrl)
    {
        //Response.Redirect("Templates.aspx");
    }

    protected void Login1_LoggedIn(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Redirect(Login1.DestinationPageUrl);
    }
}
```

Any suggestions are welcome.
Thanks & Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using an ASP:LOGIN control, you can specify "DestinationPageUrl" which is the destination page shown to the user when the log in is successful. This control will reside at "~/LogOn.aspx"

```
<asp:Login ID="Login1" runat="server" DestinationPageUrl="~/Default.aspx" CssClass="membershipcontrol" />
```

And add this to your code behind:

```
Public Partial Class LogOn
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Protected Sub Login1Function(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Login1.LoggedIn
        Response.Redirect(Login1.DestinationPageUrl)
    End Sub

End Class
```

EDIT:

OK, you are explicitly redirecting the user on line 17 using:

```
FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(Login1.UserName, true);
```

You can use this instead if you wish to send them to a static place:

```
Response.Redirect(Login1.DestinationPageUrl);
```

Comment: Thank you very much David, this is excellent. However, after implementing the DestinationPageUrl on my logon page, it still won't redirect to the "Templates.aspx". It redirect user to any pages that user visited before login. Any suggestions?

Comment: Updated the answer to include some code that will need added to the code-behind. This should override the "ReturnUrl" parameter, if it exists.

Comment: Dear David, thank you very much for your solution. I have done just that, unfortunately it won't redirect me to the tempalte.aspx. I have added my server side code to the question as well. Thanks again.

Comment: I altered my response to correct the "handles" statement, it is critical that the IDs match or else the event will not be raised. Can you try to place a debugging breakpoint inside this function, to be certain it is called (or not) and launch the application in debug mode? Can you also put a breakpoint in "Sub Login1_Authenticate()"?

Comment: After reviewing the full code-behind you added, you are explicitly redirecting the user on line 17, to "ReturnUrl" using this line of code.

Comment: oops !!! yes, I forgot about that, it is now working perfectly !!! Thank you very much David for all of your help.